# requirejs: parse a file and return its dependencies

Tags: requirejs

I have a situation where I need to load (via AJAX in a browser) a file that defines a requirejs module (without executing it) and get back a list of its dependencies.

Ie, given a file that starts with

```
requirejs(["foo/bar", "foo/baz"], function(bar, baz) {
```

I'd like the utility to return an array like

```
["foo/bar", "foo/baz"]
```

I've found some solutions that will do it using r.js (for example, the ones outlined here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/requirejs/4C0deWFqpZY/mkZFlw2r_k4J), but nothing to do it in a browser. I can just parse out the require statement myself, but that seems suboptimal. Has anyone come across any solutions for this?

Comment: By dependencies, you mean dependencies of dependencies recursively which requirejs does?

Comment: Doesn't need to be recursive. I've updated my question with an example.